# Alternating harmonic series with logarithmic exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-analysis

Let be $n > 0$ an integer.

Let be $u_n = \dfrac{(-1)^{[\ln n]}}{n}$ with $[x]$ the floor part of $x$.

Does $\sum u_n$ converges?

What I have tried: we summed over the set of integers where $[\ln n]$ was constant and got an asymptotic relation of the cardinal of a such set, eventually we deduce a new expression which is divergent. I'm not exactly convinced whether I'm allowed to do this process because the series may not be absolutely convergent.

Comment: Is the sequence of partial sums a Cauchy sequence? What you did so far should answer this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternating Series Test Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714780/alternating-series-test-proof)

Comment: Sorry.  Confused $[\ln n]$ with $n$.

Comment: Consider the partial sums up to $n=e^x$ for some $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just note that $\sum_{j=e^k}^{e^{(k+1)-1}} \frac 1 j\geq \int_{e^{k}}^{e^{(k+1)-1}} \frac 1 x dx =\ln (e^{(k+1)}-1) - \ln (e^k) =\ln \frac {e^{(k+1)}-1} {e^k} \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$. This shows that the partial sums of the original series do not form a Cauchy sequence. Hence the series is divergent.