# Modified alternating harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-functions, conditional-convergence

I am having trouble characterizing the types of alternating with-differing-period harmonic series which converge. For example, $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ converges, but what about $1+\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{9} \dots$ ($2$ positive terms and $1$ negative term). Can we characterize how far the gaps can be between negative terms?

Comment: [$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2714780/290189).

Comment: Choosing $n$ negative terms and $p>n$ positive terms in succession yields partial sums going to $+\infty$, as can be seen by estimating the sum of $n$ negative and $p$ positive terms, all consecutive. Likewise if $p<n$, with partial sums going to $-\infty$. If $p=n$ the series converges. You are asking about the case $(p,n)=(2,1)$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter The question is about another series...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463991/does-the-series-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-frac15-fr?rq=1

Comment: @RobertZ As you might remember, the version you first hurried to post was not even dealing with the convergence/divergence of the series. Note that the current version turns to some technical estimates, quite unneeded, rather than to the real mathematical reason why the series diverges. Finally the hint you saw fit to add at the end shows that the main part of your answer is a duplicate. As such, you might have wanted to concentrate on the generalization the OP is asking about at the end of their question. Just my two cents, since you are asking.

Comment: @RobertZ For example, dealing with such a worn out question, already asked several times on the site, I would find more exciting to see a proof of the fact that, if the real valued vector $A=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)$ is such that $$\sum_{i=1}^ka_i=0$$ then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}n$$ converges, where, by definition, for every $n\geqslant0$ and $1\leqslant i\leqslant k$,$$a_{kn+i}=a_i$$ and that the reason for this is the "slice" estimate $$\sum_{n=k\ell+1}^{k\ell+\ell}\frac{a_n}n=\frac{c_A}{\ell^2}+O\left(\frac1{\ell^3}\right)$$ when $\ell\to\infty$, for some constant $c_A$.

Comment: ...And that, if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ka_i\ne0$ then the series $\sum\limits_n\frac{a_n}n$ diverges.

Comment: @Did For the convergence when $\sum_{i=1}^ka_i=0$, just apply Dirichlet's test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: ...And that, for each $k\geqslant2$, there exists some vectors $A$ of size $k$ such that the sum of a slice is of order $\ell^{-k}$, thus yielding a convergence at rate $\ell^{-k+1}$, but not better.

Comment: @RobertZ Sorry but you may have mistaken my comments (and I am already regretting to have posted them). The problem is not whether I can prove the assertions in my comments or not (I can, thanks) but what could be a valuable answer to the present question.

Comment: @Did I understand your comments perfectly. I just gave another mathematical reason for the convergence. The question is a duplicate and my answer is not useful. It's fine.